# R bookdown Error in enquo : could not find function "enquo" calls: local ... hook_eval -> withVisable -> eval -> eval

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, bookdown, gitbook

I'm working on a book with bookdown.

Recently, when knitting the entire book I sometimes get errors like the one above, sometimes with %>% or other libraries I have loaded previously in the .Rmd.

What I have found is that if I go into the _bookdown_files or _book and delete the corresponding _cache and _files folder and then try to build again, now the book will build but it will need to re-render the entire chapter which can take some time.

I'm also looking for advice on bookdown - I want to create a PDF to go along with the HTML site but not all of the functionality such as DT or other graphs carry over - how does one manage two different versions in the same project?

I guess I'm looking for any other clues as to how to use bookdown.

Comment: This is more of a workflow question, without a specific code question. When writing a PDF book, you will look interactive functionality, some R outputs get saved as "webshots" from HTML when they get rendered to PDF

Comment: Any ideas about the knitting of the book? I now have two chapters I'm getting various errors from. I have to delete two chapters now each time I want to re-render a particular section. There only appear to be one or two problematic chapters I have to nuke the _cache and _files for

This is only the GitBook, I haven't attempted to knit to PDF yet.

Comment: I would break your problem into smaller chunks, only work on 1 chapter, and resolve the issue before adding the 2nd chapter. Make sure all your libraries are installed and all your data files are in a root directory. Personally I like HTML and would only use HTML gitbook